# Shower leaking after increasing water pressure

Tags: shower

I slightly increased the hot and cold valves on a single handle knob for the shower.  The very first shower taken after that was leaking into the room down below it. Did I increase the pressure too much? If so, can this be repaired by simply decreasing the pressure?

Comment: `can this be repaired by simply decreasing the pressure`  ... no, there is an actual leak somewhere

Comment: It depends on where the leak is. If the leak is at a valve packing or o ring seal reducing the pressure may solve the problem. To know for sure the source of the leak will need to be found. A pinhole leak in a pipe may be fine at a lower pressure but over time it will get worse even at a lower pressure.